# Restrict access of a database login through ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

There are 5 databases in a server (Eg: db1,db2,db3,db4,db5)

There is an SQL server Login "usera".

The login currently has access of all databases.

I want to allow usera access of only database db1.

So I do this,

**SQL Server Mgmt Studio -> Security -> Logins -> usera (Right Click Properties)

Under User Mapping Option, I uncheck all databases except db1 & click on OK.**

But I get this error :
**Notice the username dbo.**

[image]

Any Ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message implies that the user "usera" is the owner of one or more databases.  Check each database to see who is the owner.

To change the owner of a database use the Alter Authorization command. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359(v=sql.105).aspx

If you are old-school, you might prefer the sp_changedbowner command https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.110).aspx